# ezSQL Object(stdClass) Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, stdclass, ezsql

```
$db = new ezSQL_mysql($user,$pass,$db,$server);
$user = $db->get_row("SELECT id,last FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
var_dump($user);
```

The dump returns this:

```
object(stdClass)#11 (5) {
   ["id"]=>
   string(1) "4"
   ["last"]=>
   string(19) "2013-01-06 14:48:24"
}
```

However, in attempting to ask for the id of the user via the object:

```
$uid=$user->id;
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Comment: I would like to also state, PDO cannot be used in this specific scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own problem by eding the class and pushing get_object_vars:

```
if ( $output == OBJECT )
        {
            $out = $this->last_result[$y]?$this->last_result[$y]:null;
            return get_object_vars($out);
        }
```